# JS Prevent duplicates when using .push()

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I grab a list of data from the server and I have to convert it.
Part of this is turning it into a 3 dimensional array. After the "myArr[i].children.push(temp);" it leaves copies of the objects that were pushed in the root of the array. Can I either push without copying or how would I delete these? (I have underscore js included, I know they have good array functions :))

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    myArr[i].children = [];
    for (var q = 0; q < myArr.length; q++) {
        if (myArr[i].id == myArr[q].parentid) {
            var temp = {
                id: myArr[q].id,
                index: myArr[q].index,
                text: myArr[q].text
            }
            myArr[i].children.push(temp);
        };
    };  
};
```

**The Data**

```
[{
    "id": "5",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "Device Guides",
    "index": "0"
}, {
    "id": "6",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "Pre-Sales Evaluation",
    "index": "1"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "Router Setup Guides",
    "index": "2"
}, {
    "id": "9",
    "parentid": "7",
    "text": "Sonicwall",
    "index": "0"
}, {
    "id": "10",
    "parentid": "5",
    "text": "Grandstream GXP-21XX",
    "index": "1"
}, {
    "id": "11",
    "parentid": "5",
    "text": "Polycom Soundstation\/Soundpoint",
    "index": "2"
}, {
    "id": "12",
    "parentid": "7",
    "text": "Cisco",
    "index": "1"
}, {
    "id": "15",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "Post-Sales Implementation Check List",
    "index": "7"
}, {
    "id": "16",
    "parentid": "15",
    "text": "Porting and New Number Details",
    "index": "0"
}, {
    "id": "18",
    "parentid": "15",
    "text": "Partner Setup",
    "index": "1"
}, {
    "id": "19",
    "parentid": "15",
    "text": "test",
    "index": "2"
}, {
    "id": "20",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "test",
    "index": "11"
}, {
    "id": "21",
    "parentid": "15",
    "text": "test",
    "index": "3"
}, {
    "id": "23",
    "parentid": "5",
    "text": "New Polycom",
    "index": "0"
}, {
    "id": "24",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "Test Markup",
    "index": "14"
}, {
    "id": "25",
    "parentid": "0",
    "text": "test",
    "index": "15"
}]
```

**After it is formated:**

```
{
    "children": [{
        "id": "5",
        "parentid": "0",
        "text": "Device Guides",
        "index": "1",
        "children": [{
            "id": "10",
            "index": "0",
            "text": "Grandstream GXP-21XX"
        }, {
            "id": "11",
            "index": "1",
            "text": "Polycom Soundstation/Soundpoint"
        }, {
            "id": "23",
            "index": "2",
            "text": "New Polycom"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "6",
        "parentid": "0",
        "text": "Pre-Sales Evaluation",
        "index": "0",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "7",
        "parentid": "0",
        "text": "Router Setup Guides",
        "index": "2",
        "children": [{
            "id": "9",
            "index": "0",
            "text": "Sonicwall"
        }, {
            "id": "12",
            "index": "1",
            "text": "Cisco"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "9",
        "parentid": "7",
        "text": "Sonicwall",
        "index": "0",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "10",
        "parentid": "5",
        "text": "Grandstream GXP-21XX",
        "index": "0",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "11",
        "parentid": "5",
        "text": "Polycom Soundstation/Soundpoint",
        "index": "1",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "12",
        "parentid": "7",
        "text": "Cisco",
        "index": "1",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "15",
        "parentid": "0",
        "text": "Post-Sales Implementation Check List",
        "index": "7",
        "children": [{
            "id": "16",
            "index": "0",
            "text": "Porting and New Number Details"
        }, {
            "id": "18",
            "index": "1",
            "text": "Partner Setup"
        }, {
            "id": "19",
            "index": "2",
            "text": "test"
        }, {
            "id": "21",
            "index": "3",
            "text": "test"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "16",
        "parentid": "15",
        "text": "Porting and New Number Details",
        "index": "0",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "18",
        "parentid": "15",
        "text": "Partner Setup",
        "index": "1",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "19",
        "parentid": "15",
        "text": "test",
        "index": "2",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "20",
        "parentid": "0",
        "text": "test",
        "index": "11",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "21",
        "parentid": "15",
        "text": "test",
        "index": "3",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "23",
        "parentid": "5",
        "text": "New Polycom",
        "index": "2",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "24",
        "parentid": "0",
        "text": "Test Markup",
        "index": "14",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "25",
        "parentid": "0",
        "text": "test",
        "index": "15",
        "children": []
    }]
}
```

Comment: It would help if you shared a data example that you are using with the code above... or better yet, a demo! :P

Comment: `var temp = {}` is what issues the (shallow) copy. If you don't want that and keep a reference to the original instead do `.push(myArr[q])`

Comment: Don't use the `temp` variable, and instead do: `myArr[i].children.push(myArr.splice(q, 1));`. Of course, you'll have to loop backwards instead of forwards

Comment: Okay, I'll try that out, in the mean time I added the data sets.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for adding the data. And actually, my solution won't work 100%. I realized the loops loop over the same array, so the `splice`, which will remove the element from the array, will mess up the outer loop. At least I think so. I'm trying to figure out how to handle it though.

Comment: @Ian thank you :)! I have been playing around with this for several hours and cannot get it haha.

Comment: if you did a sort on parentId, you could splice and move the chunks safely after that. depends on the size of the array how efficient that will be though...

Comment: @DavidMcMullin eventually.. 300+, right now there is only a handfull. I'd like to optimize it before it gets big haha.

Comment: good point =) I notice your output data is actually an object - is there any reason you actually need to preserve the original array? You could just loop through - parentId 0 - > add to object, otherwise add to objInArray, then the dups would be left behind in the original array, which you can discard, in favour of the constructed object.

Comment: @DavidMcMullin Good point, could you answer with and example of this? As long as the format stays the same except for the dupes gone of course I'll be happy :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go

```
tree = {0: {children: []}}

data.forEach(function(x) {
    x.children = tree[x.id] ? tree[x.id].children : [];
    tree[x.id] = x;

    if(!tree[x.parentid])
        tree[x.parentid] = {children: []}
    tree[x.parentid].children.push(x)
})

result = tree[0].children
```

This solution is linear (iterates over the array just once) and doesn't require any pre-sorting.

http://jsfiddle.net/U47WY/

and here's how to convert the tree back to the linear array:

```
function flatten(source) {
    return source.reduce(function(a, x) {
        var children = x.children;
        delete x.children;
        return a.concat([x], flatten(x.children))
    }, []);
}
```

Comment: Just to remind anyone - `forEach` doesn't work in IE before version 9. But there is a polyfill for it, or you could just use a `for` loop.

Comment: @thg435 Just wondering, what would it take to reverse this script to bring it back to the old format to send backt o the server? I have a script that works but yours is much more condensed and faster.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from a friendly discussion in the comments :

```
var zeroObj = {"children":[]};
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    if(myArr[i].parentid === 0) {
        zeroObj.children.push(myArr[i]);
    } else {
        for (var q = 0; q < myArr.length; q++) {
            if (myArr[i].parentid == myArr[q].id) {
                myArr[q].children = myArr[q].children || [];
                myArr[q].children.push(myArr[i]);
            };
        }; 
    }
};
```

Comment: David, if I could accept both answers I would, but I like how condensed his is :) Thank you for this though!

Comment: You're absolutely right! I enjoyed the discussion and I agree completely that it's better to take the method that only loops once =)